# Data Grid View Cell Event (Data Hidden)

Tags: c#, view, grid

I have a DataGrid View which is bound to the Binding Source. All the Cells are Read Only. The Problem that I have is when I click the cell the data is hidden, when it goes to other cell that data comes up. I am trying to figure it out what going on. Can some one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess here... If the selected cell background color and font color inside the cell are the same, the data might appear invisible.